# 404 error while hosting a static website using Google AppEngine

Tags: html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to follow all the steps as according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/How_do_you_host_your_website_on_Google_App_Engine) blog here to host a static website using google app engine. The app.yaml file looks like this:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
static_files: website/index.html
upload: website/index.html

- url: /
static_dir: website
```

Say my project ID is abcd-123. When I go to abcd-123.appspot.com, it's giving the 404 error. (Also, I am using the same folder they've provided for hosting). Please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your app dir structure, including your app.yaml and the index.html files?

Comment: Just as given in the blog. I've used the same downloadable folder they've provided. Besides that, I even tried making a single directory with just one index.html file and an app.yaml (as shown in the official documentation), but the same problem is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have a `website` folder, and inside of it, you have `index.html` file, along with a self created `app.yaml` file. Also make sure that you mention your project id while running the `set project` command and not project name!

Comment: Ya that worked, by renaming the folder as "website". Maybe this was according to the app.yaml they provided. So it's like, you basically should have the same name of the folder as specified in your app.yaml. Thanks :)